# seperate integers similar to text to columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R from the SAS world and I have a txt file from an old database and I am working to convert it into a more user friendly csv file for analysis, I stripped pagination and moved product names into columns of the matrix using zoo, I am trying to separate integers separated by a space into individual columns.

I have tried strsplit, gsub to remove integers after the space, etc

```r
 data_19_3$sale = as.numeric(strsplit(data_19_3$V2,split=" +")[[1]])
```

> `Error in strsplit(data_19_3$V2, split = " +") : non-character argument`

These data are in one column V2 of my dataframe separated by a space and I would like them in their own column

```r
V2
-1.000        49.850 
-1.000        64.850 
-42.500       -21.800 
-85.000      -116.800 
-14.940      -166.740
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in the code.

1) Based on the error, the column seems to be `factor` and not `character` class and `strsplit` requires a `character` input.  One way is to convert to `character` class with `as.character`

2) Subsetting the `list` output with `[[1]]`.  Extracts only the first element.  We need to loop over the `list` and convert to `numeric`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(data_19_3$V2),split=" +"), function(x) as.numeric(x[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks you akrun a minor change to your code as.numeric(x[2] resulted in the desired output